# Sending a pre-saved message (as a string) using SmsManager

Tags: android, smsmanager

i am realy new to android developing and i get stuck a lot. In my application i am trying to send a pre-saved message to user specified numbers. I was able to send a message with smsmanager ( basic tutorials helped alot ) but i want the program to send a message which user has pre defined with gps location information.

I created a string in the Strings.xml file but i can't reach the string from the fragment i created. 
So basicly how can i send a pre written messages + gps info to pre chosen numbers ? ( the number and message will be chosen by the user for future use )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String stringineed =getString(R.string.nameofstringyourneedinstringsxml);
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
Geocoder gCoder = new Geocoder(context);
List<Address> addresses = null;
try {addresses = gCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
String addressinfo = "addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + "\n"+ addresses.get(0).getPremises() + "\n"+ addresses.get(0).getCountryCode() + "\n"+ addresses.get(0).getPostalCode() + "\n""}
String prewrittenmessage =("This is the prewrittenmessage"+addressinfo);
//or stringinneed+""+ addressinfo
String phone = "some chosen number to be sent to";
Intent sendtoemail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phone, null, prewrittenmessage ,null, null);
```

Comment: İt doesn't resolve the location and content. Should i import something ? I have already imported these ;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;